# ElasticSearch 6.4: Stored fields not being stored

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch 6.4 I have a database where I mapped several fields and specified several as stored. However, when I run a query, those fields are in _source instead of stored_fields. Did I miss something in the mapping?

Here is a simple example that reproduces the issue:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/testdb
```

then

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/testdb/_mapping/_doc
```

with body

```
{
    "properties": {
        "field1_indexed": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "field2_not_indexed": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false,
            "store": true
        },
        "field3_stored": {
            "type": "text",
            "store": true
        }
    }
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/testdb/_doc/1
```

with body

```
{
    "field1_indexed": "field 1",
    "field2_not_indexed": "field 2",
    "field3_stored": "field 3"
}
```

now request http://localhost:9200/testdb/_search?_source=false and get this back:

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards": 
{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits": 
{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits": 
[{"_index":"testdb","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_score":1.0}]}}
```

Note that there is no "stored_fields" element despite "field2_not_indexed" and "field3_stored" explicitly declaring store=true in the mapping. If I don't turn off _source, all three fields are output in the _source element.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs under searching, it turns out that you have to explicitly tell the search query that you want stored fields. Thus you either need to specify it in the URL, http://localhost:9200/testdb/_search?stored_fields=*, or in the request body.

```
{
    "stored_fields": ["*"]
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured out! Also worth noting that the `_source` will always contain whatever document you sent in the first place. The full unaltered document is stored in the `_source` field and will always return unless you specify `_source: false`. But fields stored individually have to be explicitly requested as you figured out.